# Dias úteis e API Java 8, como verificar?

Tags: java, data, java-8

Como verificar se um dia é útil utilizando a API do Java 8?
É possível verificar se é sábado ou domingo, mas como verificar por exemplo feriado como 7 de Setembro (Independência do Brasil) ou Sexta-Feira Santa?

```
int ano = 2014;
int mes = 5;
YearMonth anoMes = YearMonth.of(ano, mes);


List<LocalDate> listaDosDiasUteisDoMes = new ArrayList<>();

for(int dia=1; dia <= anoMes.lengthOfMonth(); dia++){ 
  LocalDate data = anoMes.atDay(dia); 

  if(!data.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) &&   
    !data.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)){

      listaDosDiasUteisDoMes.add(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Você pretende fazer isso offline ou tem uma conexão com internet?

Comment: Inicialmente offline. Mas se for o caso modifico para online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para isso você precisa definir a sua própria lista de feriados. Existem várias APIs que fornecem este tipo de informação, como a [Jollyday](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/) (tem um exemplo no final), e várias outras listadas [neste link](https://www.programmableweb.com/category/holidays/api).

Caso você não queira usar uma API, pode ter seu próprio cadastro também (e neste caso, é algo que você terá que fazer manualmente).

Outro problema dos feriados é que nem todos possuem datas fixas (como a Páscoa, Carnaval, etc, que todo ano caem em datas diferentes), e devem ser calculados de acordo com o ano. Além disso, há os feriados nacionais, estaduais e municipais, e você deve decidir se vai incluí-los ou não na sua lista.

De qualquer forma, independente da solução escolhida (usar uma API externa, cadastrar manualmente, incluir somente feriados nacionais, etc), basta que você guarde todos os feriados em um [`java.util.Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), e em seguida verifique se a data está no `Set` (usando o método [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)), mais ou menos assim:

```
Set<LocalDate> feriados = // feriados, ver mais abaixo como montar este Set
for (int dia = 1; dia <= anoMes.lengthOfMonth(); dia++) {
    LocalDate data = anoMes.atDay(dia);

    if (data.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY
        && data.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY
        && !feriados.contains(data)) {
        listaDosDiasUteisDoMes.add(data);
    }
}
```

Como [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) é um `enum`, posso compará-los usando `==` e `!=` ([não precisa usar `equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1750435)).

---

Para montar o `Set` com os feriados, eu sugiro separar em 2 métodos: um para os feriados fixos (que é mais fácil, já que sempre caem no mesmo dia todo ano) e outro para os feriados móveis.

Eu sugiro que você passe o ano como parâmetro para estes métodos, assim você consegue construir uma lista de [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), que é o que você precisa.

```
// feriados que acontecem todo ano na mesma data, gerar lista para o ano específico
public Set<LocalDate> getFeriadosFixos(int year) {
    Set<LocalDate> dates = new HashSet<>();

    // 7 de setembro
    dates.add(LocalDate.of(year, 9, 7));
    // natal
    dates.add(LocalDate.of(year, 12, 25));
    // ... adicione todos os outros

    return dates;
}
```

Este método não considera as "emendas" de feriados (se cai na terça, emenda a segunda, então esses dois dias não são úteis). Se quiser, basta verificar se o feriado é uma terça ou quinta (comparando o `DayOfWeek`):

```
// 7 de setembro
LocalDate seteSetembro = LocalDate.of(year, 9, 7);
dates.add(seteSetembro);
// se cai na terça, inclui a segunda ("emenda" de feriado)
if (seteSetembro.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.TUESDAY) {
    dates.add(seteSetembro.minusDays(1));
}
// se cai na quinta, inclui a sexta ("emenda" de feriado)
if (seteSetembro.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.THURSDAY) {
    dates.add(seteSetembro.plusDays(1));
}
```

Faça isso para todos os feriados que podem ser "emendados".

Para os feriados móveis, há uma fórmula para calculá-los (procure no Google e encontrará vários sites explicando). Vou usar uma que achei:

```
// calcula páscoa, carnaval, corpus christi e sexta-feira santa
public Set<LocalDate> getFeriadosMoveis(int year) {
    Set<LocalDate> dates = new HashSet<>();

    LocalDate pascoa;
    LocalDate carnaval;
    LocalDate corpusChristi;
    LocalDate sextaFeiraSanta;

    int a = year % 19;
    int b = year / 100;
    int c = year % 100;
    int d = b / 4;
    int e = b % 4;
    int f = (b + 8) / 25;
    int g = (b - f + 1) / 3;
    int h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30;
    int i = c / 4;
    int k = c % 4;
    int l = (32 + 2 * e + 2 * i - h - k) % 7;
    int m = (a + 11 * h + 22 * l) / 451;
    int month = (h + l - 7 * m + 114) / 31;
    int day = ((h + l - 7 * m + 114) % 31) + 1;

    pascoa = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);

    // Carnaval 47 dias antes da pascoa (sempre cai na terça)
    carnaval = pascoa.minusDays(47);

    // CorpusChristi 60 dias apos a pascoa
    corpusChristi = pascoa.plusDays(60);

    sextaFeiraSanta = pascoa.minusDays(2);

    // páscoa cai sempre no domingo, entao não precisaria adicionar como feriado
    // dates.add(pascoa);

    // carnaval: adicionar um dia antes e depois (emenda de segunda e quarta-feira de cinzas)
    dates.add(carnaval);
    dates.add(carnaval.minusDays(1)); // emenda a segunda-feira
    dates.add(carnaval.plusDays(1)); // quarta-feira de cinzas

    // corpus christi, emendar (adicionar a sexta)
    dates.add(corpusChristi);
    // if apenas para confirmar se é quinta-feira
    if (corpusChristi.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.THURSDAY) {
        dates.add(corpusChristi.plusDays(1)); // adicionar a sexta-feira
    }

    dates.add(sextaFeiraSanta);

    return dates;
}
```

Repare que incluí também as "emendas" de feriados. Se não quiser, basta remover as respectivas linhas.

Para criar o `Set` com todos os feriados, basta usar os dois métodos acima e juntar tudo em um único `Set`:

```
Set<LocalDate> feriados = new HashSet<>();
feriados.addAll(getFeriadosFixos(year));
feriados.addAll(getFeriadosMoveis(year));
```

O parâmetro `year` pode ser o ano que você está usando (`anoMes.getYear()`), por exemplo.

---

Apenas como complemento, é possível encapsular a lógica de verificação em um [`java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalQuery.html). A diferença é que esta interface trabalha com um [`java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) (ao invés de um tipo específico como `LocalDate`), então o código para verificar o dia da semana é um pouco diferente:

```
public class VerificaDiaUtil implements TemporalQuery<Boolean> {

    private Set<LocalDate> feriados = new HashSet<>();

    public VerificaDiaUtil() {
        this.feriados = // constrói a lista de feriados
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean queryFrom(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
        // obter o dia da semana
        DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(temporal);
        return dow != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY && dow != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY
               // extrair o LocalDate e verificar se está no Set de feriados
               && !feriados.contains(LocalDate.from(temporal));
    }
}
```

Com isso a classe `VerificaDiaUtil` fica responsável por manter a lista de feriados. Se quiser, você pode alterar o construtor para receber o ano como parâmetro (e aí ela constrói apenas os feriados daquele ano), ou então ela já carrega os feriados de vários anos de uma só vez. Fica a seu critério.

Para usar esta classe, basta usar o método [`query`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#query-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery-) de `LocalDate`:

```
VerificaDiaUtil diaUtil = new VerificaDiaUtil();
for (int dia = 1; dia <= anoMes.lengthOfMonth(); dia++) {
    LocalDate data = anoMes.atDay(dia);
    if (data.query(diaUtil)) {
        listaDosDiasUteisDoMes.add(data);
    }
}
```

Como `TemporalQuery` recebe um `java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor`, ele funciona com outras classes também (desde que estas tenham dia, mês e ano - e consequentemente, um dia da semana), como [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) ou [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Se você passar uma classe que não possui dia da semana (como [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), por exemplo, que só possui as horas), este código lancará uma exceção.

---

Apenas para citar um exemplo com uma API, segue uma solução com Jollyday. Fica bem similar ao código acima, a única diferença é que você não precisa mais calcular os feriados manualmente, podendo delegar esta tarefa para a API:

```java
import de.jollyday.HolidayCalendar;
import de.jollyday.HolidayManager;
import de.jollyday.ManagerParameters;

public class VerificaDiaUtil implements TemporalQuery<Boolean> {
    private HolidayManager manager;
    public VerificaDiaUtil() {
        // usa os feriados do Jollyday, em vez de calcular manualmente
        this.manager = HolidayManager.getInstance(ManagerParameters.create(HolidayCalendar.BRAZIL));
    }
    @Override
    public Boolean queryFrom(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
        // obter o dia da semana
        DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(temporal);
        return dow != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY && dow != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY
                // extrair o LocalDate e verificar se é feriado
                && !this.manager.isHoliday(LocalDate.from(temporal));
    }
}

// A forma de usar é a mesma do código anterior
VerificaDiaUtil diaUtil = new VerificaDiaUtil();
for (int dia = 1; dia <= anoMes.lengthOfMonth(); dia++) {
    LocalDate data = anoMes.atDay(dia);
    if (data.query(diaUtil)) {
        listaDosDiasUteisDoMes.add(data);
    }
}
```

No caso do Jollyday, ainda dá para verificar feriados estaduais, municipais, etc, ou ainda criar sua própria lista. Para mais detalhes, consulte a [documentação](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/usage.html).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a [**Google Calendar API**](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/) da seguinte forma proposta pela documentação:

> ```
> import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
> import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
> import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
> import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
> import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
> import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
> import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
> import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
> import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
> import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
> import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
> import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
> import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
> import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
> import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events;
>
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.io.InputStream;
> import java.io.InputStreamReader;
> import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
> import java.util.Collections;
> import java.util.List;
>
> public class CalendarQuickstart {
>     private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Java Quickstart";
>     private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
>     private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
>
>     /**
>     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
>     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials/ folder.
>     */
>     private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY);
>     private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "credentials.json";
>
>     /**
>     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
>     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
>     * @return An authorized Credential object.
>     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
>     */
>     private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
>         // Load client secrets.
>         InputStream in = CalendarQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
>         GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
>
>         // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
>         GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
>                 HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
>                 .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
>                 .setAccessType("offline")
>                 .build();
>         return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
>         // Build a new authorized API client service.
>         final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
>         Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
>                 .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
>                 .build();
>
>         // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
>         DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
>         Events events = service.events().list("primary")
>                 .setMaxResults(10)
>                 .setTimeMin(now)
>                 .setOrderBy("startTime")
>                 .setSingleEvents(true)
>                 .execute();
>         List<Event> items = events.getItems();
>         if (items.isEmpty()) {
>             System.out.println("No upcoming events found.");
>         } else {
>             System.out.println("Upcoming events");
>             for (Event event : items) {
>                 DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
>                 if (start == null) {
>                     start = event.getStart().getDate();
>                 }
>                 System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", event.getSummary(), start);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso eu tenho uma tabela de feriados e com ela eu utilizado as rotinas abaixo:

```
private LocalDate calculaDia(LocalDate data, int diaMesSemanaAno, boolean trataFinalDeSemana, boolean trataFeriado) {
    int maisOuMenosUm = 1;
    // trata quando quiser subtrair uma data
    if (diaMesSemanaAno < 0) {
        diaMesSemanaAno = diaMesSemanaAno * -1;
        maisOuMenosUm = -1;
    }
    while (diaMesSemanaAno > 0) {
        data = data.plusDays(maisOuMenosUm);
        // quando for final de semana
        if (trataFinalDeSemana) {
            // verifica se e final de semana...
            data = eFinalSemana(data, maisOuMenosUm);
        }

        // quando tem feriado
        if (trataFeriado) {
            data = eFeriado(data, maisOuMenosUm);
        }

        diaMesSemanaAno--;
    }
    return data;
}

private LocalDate eFeriado(LocalDate data, int somaSubtraiUm) {
    String feriado = DateUtil.getData(data, DateUtil.DATA_BR_PADRAO_BARRAS);
    TwebferiadosTO twebferiadosTO = new TwebferiadosTO();
    twebferiadosTO.setDataFormatada(feriado);
    twebferiadosTO = consultar(twebferiadosTO);
    if (twebferiadosTO != null) {
        data = data.plusDays(somaSubtraiUm);
        data = eFeriado(data, somaSubtraiUm);
        //verifica se nao e final de semana
        data = eFinalSemana(data, somaSubtraiUm);
    }
    return data;
}

private LocalDate eFinalSemana(LocalDate data, int somaSubtraiUm) {
    if (data.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY
            || data.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
        data = data.plusDays(somaSubtraiUm);
        data = eFinalSemana(data, somaSubtraiUm);
    }
    return data;
}
```

- Valida feriado em sequencia. Ex. Carnaval
- Valida feriado que cai no final de semana