# (C#) - Receber Uma data pelo Console, e retornar se o dia da data recebida é Considerado Dia útil? Considerar Feriados

Tags: c#

O usuário irá digitar uma data (DD/MM/YYYY), e o Programa deve retornar se o dia referente a data é útil ou não.

Já fiz parte do código considerando Final de Semana (sábado e Domingo) como não útil. Quero saber se existe alguma forma (sem usar banco de dados/Tabelas) de considerar os feriados também.

```
 this.DataIni = Convert.ToDateTime(dtIniString);
       diaSemana = DataIni.DayOfWeek.ToString();
       if(diaSemana == "Saturday" || diaSemana == "Sunday")
       {}
```

Comment: provavelmente não, tendo em vista que muitos feriados não tem dias especificos e vao mudando de ano pra ano..

Comment: Feriados devem ser dados estáticos e definidos na sua aplicação, não tem como saber se o dia é feriado ou não sem nada para auxiliar!

Comment: *"feriados"* é algo bem amplo, pois depende do país (e no Brasil, por exemplo, ainda há feriados estaduais, municipais, etc), há os fixos (caem todo ano no mesmo dia), os móveis (carnaval, páscoa, etc, que todo ano caem em datas diferentes, mas [há como calcular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/320353/112052)) e por aí vai. Então tudo depende de quais feriados você quer considerar. Se não quer consultar de um banco, terá que usar uma [API externa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43783619), ou [uma lib](https://www.google.com/search?q=holiday+api+for+C%23), ou ainda gerar as datas manualmente

Comment: Como feriados são variados, precisará de uma API, como essa, por exemplo: http://www.calendario.com.br/api_feriados_municipais_estaduais_nacionais.php

Comment: Entendi, Obrigada. Acredito que o uso de API seja a melhor opção para mim no momento.

Comment: Indo um pouco mais além, há os feriados (ou então "dias não-úteis") que dependem do contexto, como as "emendas" (quando o feriado cai na quinta, a sexta também é dia útil? depende de onde você trabalha), seguradoras não trabalham [no dia do securitário](http://www.securitariosp.org.br/Arquivos/CCTSEGURADORAS2018Sao%20Paulo.pdf), o judiciário [possui feriados próprios](https://bit.ly/2SxHanZ) e por aí vai. Talvez não se aplique ao seu caso específico, mas a definição de dia útil (no sentido de "dia em que as pessoas trabalham") varia bastante conforme o contexto.

Comment: Como mencionado por alguns colegas, feriado é específico de cada país, então não há como saber se é feriado sem uma "base" de consulta previamente "populada". A expressão "banco de dados" é bem ampla e não se refere apenas, por exemplo, ao SQL Server, Oracle, etc, mas a tudo que pode, de alguma forma, "armazenar" informações. Em sua pergunta você diz "sem usar banco de dados/Tabelas", acredito que esta se referindo a bancos de dados relacionais, ou não. Já pensou em usar um arquivo texto onde há todas as datas de feriados cadastradas?

Comment: Pessoal, Como Sinalizar a Resposta da pergunta? Como a pergunta está pendente, não consigo "Fechar" ela.