# Calcular data sem contar finais de semana e feriados

Tags: data, delphi-berlin

Estou necessitando de calcular datas futuras através de uma quantidade de dias, porém não se deve contar os finais de semanas e feriados.

Vejam o exemplo: O projeto inicia dia 01/01/2020 e tem duração de 25 dias, ou seja, ele tem de terminar dia 29/01/2020 (pulando os fins de semana e o feriado do dia 1 de janeiro).

Eu fiz um `if` com `IncDay` mas isso só fez pular o primeiro fim de semana, ou seja, não tenho nem ideia por onde começar pra resolver esse problema.

Segue o código que fiz até o momento:

```
    procedure TformPrincipal.QueryProjItemCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
    dtFim: TDateTime;
    dtSemFds: TDateTime;
begin

    //zerar os campos se a duração tiver vazia
    if QueryProjItemprojitem_duracao.Value=0
    then
        begin
            QueryProjItemvlcustorecurso.AsFloat:=0;
        end
    else
        begin
            //Calcula a data de acordo com a duração sem FDS
            dtFim:=(QueryProjItemprojitem_dt_inicio.AsDateTime + QueryProjItemprojitem_duracao.AsInteger);

            if DayOfWeek(dtFim)=1 then
                    dtFim:= incDay(dtFim,1)
                else
                if DayOfWeek(dtFim)=7 then
                    dtFim:= incDay(dtFim,2);

            QueryProjItemdtFinal.AsDateTime :=dtFim;


            //Calcula o valor total dos recursos de acordo com a duração
            QueryProjItemvlcustorecurso.AsFloat:=
            QueryProjItemrec_vl.AsFloat * QueryProjItemprojitem_duracao.AsInteger;


        end;

end;
```

Comment: Olá Felipe, poste o código e aponte qual o erro ou dificuldade está encontrando.

Comment: Olá tudo bem? Eu editei a postagem e fiz a inclusão do código, obrigado

Comment: Vc precisa ter os feriados cadastrados em algum lugar, pois eles variam muito: serão feriados de qual país? Se for no Brasil, tem também feriados estaduais e municipais, será levado em conta? Tem os [feriados móveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/320353/112052), como a Páscoa e carnaval, que muda todo ano. Enfim, vc só fez um `if`, mas na verdade deveria ter feito um *loop* e ir incrementando a data N vezes (e no `if`, acrescentar uma condição verificando se a data está nesse cadastro de feriados). Eu não programo em Delphi então não vou arriscar uma resposta, mas em linhas gerais é isso...

Comment: @hkotsubo obrigado pela dica...Então, o if que eu fiz faz apenas "pular o fim de semana da   sequência" e isso realmente não é funcional pra mim. Poderia mostrar um exemplo de loop parecido com isso? Poderia ser apenas a lógica mesmo, pois é nisso que estou tendo dificuldades, dependendo pode ser que isso me ajude bastante. Os feriados eu vou fazer em uma tabela separada com inclusão manual mesmo. Muito obrigado

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso: https://ideone.com/E3ohLx (código em "portugol") - não testei esse algoritmo em nenhuma linguagem, pode ser que precise de algum ajuste

Comment: @hkotsubo estou muito agradecido pela sua ajuda, com base na lógica que disponibilizou eu desenvolvi um código que funcionou perfeitamente para meu projeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a dica do @hkotsubo, desenvolvi o seguinte código que resolveu meu problema:

```
procedure TformPrincipal.QueryProjItemCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
dtFim: TDateTime;
duracao: Integer;
begin
//zerar os campos se a duração tiver vazia
if QueryProjItemprojitem_duracao.Value=0
then
    begin
        QueryProjItemvlcustorecurso.AsFloat:=0;
    end
else
    begin
        dtFim:=QueryProjItemprojitem_dt_inicio.AsDateTime;
        duracao:=2;
        while duracao <= QueryProjItemprojitem_duracao.AsInteger do
        begin
               dtFim:= IncDay(dtFim,1);
                while (DayOfWeek(dtFim)=1) or (DayOfWeek(dtFim)=7) do
                begin
                    if DayOfWeek(dtFim)=1 then
                        dtFim:= IncDay(dtFim,1);
                    if DayOfWeek(dtFim)=7 then
                        dtFim:=IncDay(dtFim,2);
                end;
             duracao:=duracao + 1;
        end;
        QueryProjItemdtFinal.AsDateTime :=dtFim;

        //Calcula o valor total dos recursos de acordo com a duração
        QueryProjItemvlcustorecurso.AsFloat:=
        QueryProjItemrec_vl.AsFloat * 
        QueryProjItemprojitem_duracao.AsInteger;


    end;

end;
```